# iTunes URL for an iPhone app+locale

Tags: iphone, url, itunes

When in a browser it's typed an url like this:
http://itunes.apple.com/app/NAME_APP/idAPPID?mt=8
(where NAME_APP is the name of an iPhone app and APPID its identifier) it is showed the iTunes preview of the app in the USA App Store.

Is there a way to open the iTunes preview according user's locale?

Answer (score 3):

I get this link from Facebook developer, you can try this: http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=[APP-ID]

This will detect user locale.

Comment: What happens if the locale isn't available for the store item of that App id?

Comment: This format work too: [https://itunes.apple.com/app/?id=497093488](https://itunes.apple.com/app/?id=497093488)

Answer (score 2):

You can prepend the two character country code to the URL to get you the appropriate store and price, like this: `itunes.apple.com/[COUNTRY CODE]/app/NAME_APP/idAPPID?mt=8`

Here are a few examples using one of my apps:

http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/mobile-legislate/id441586657?mt=8 - English store, price in Pounds

http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/mobile-legislate/id441586657?mt=8
 - French Store, price in Euros

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mobile-legislate/id441586657?mt=8 - USA store, price in Dollars

Do be careful though, because if you use an invalid country code you'll simply get an error, and won't be redirected to a generic page.

Comment: @ltx: Thanks for the answer. I would that a french user (for example) opened http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/mobile-legislate/id441586657?mt=8, without specifying "fr" in the url. Is there an iTunes "generic" url that redirects the user on the right page according to her/his locale?

Comment: Good question, and I don't think there is. If you remove the country code completely it just sends you to the US store. It seems silly, since it would be fairly easy to do, and the desktop/mobile iTunes clients will redirect appropriately.